# Concatenate distinct strings and numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, listagg

I am trying to get a distinct concatenated list of `employee_id`s and sum their `employee_allowance`. However, I do not want to sum duplicate `employee_id`'s `employee_allowance`.

### My expected result

| name | employee_ids | allowance | this column is for explanation (not part of output) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 11Bob532, 11Bob923 | 26 | 13+13=26 because the id's are different, so we sum both |
| Sara | 12Sara833 | 93 |  |
| John | 18John243, 18John823 | 64 | 21+43=64 because we got rid of the duplicate 18John243's allowance |

### Table creation/dummy data

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
   name varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
   employee_id varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
   employee_allowance number not null
);

INSERT INTO emp (name, employee_id, employee_allowance) VALUES ('Bob', '11Bob923', 13);
INSERT INTO emp (name, employee_id, employee_allowance) VALUES ('Bob', '11Bob532', 13);
INSERT INTO emp (name, employee_id, employee_allowance) VALUES ('Sara', '12Sara833', 93);
INSERT INTO emp (name, employee_id, employee_allowance) VALUES ('John', '18John243', 21);
INSERT INTO emp (name, employee_id, employee_allowance) VALUES ('John', '18John243', 21);
INSERT INTO emp (name, employee_id, employee_allowance) VALUES ('John', '18John823', 43);
```

### My attempt

My output gives me the distinct, concatenated `employee_id`s but still sums up the duplicate `employee_allowance` row.

```
SELECT
  name,
  LISTAGG(DISTINCT employee_id, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY employee_id) "ids",
  SUM(employee_allowance)
FROM emp
GROUP BY
  name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `DISTINCT` rows first and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT name,
       LISTAGG(employee_id, ', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY employee_id) AS employee_ids,
       SUM(employee_allowance) AS allowance
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM   emp
)
GROUP BY name
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | NAME | EMPLOYEE_IDS | ALLOWANCE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Bob | 11Bob532, 11Bob923 | 26 |
> | John | 18John243, 18John823 | 64 |
> | Sara | 12Sara833 | 93 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=59379f538bfb1519005c4ff692b864b4)*